# Calculate variance of 3 or more attributes with known frequencies

Tags: java, statistics, machine-learning, data-mining

I want to calculate the variance in a dataset collected at a given time (t) for which we know the frequency of the conditional and decision attributes.

Every conditional attribute can take 3 possible values while the outcome consists of a two-classe attribute, as can be seen in the picture given below. What I need is to calculate the variance of this given data snapshot.

I would also be interested in sample code or algorithm.

![image]

Comment: Fatal: `DontUnderstandQuestionError` (sorry: what are the values about? time? classes? conditional attribute? .. and, is this homework or paid?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better off asking this on the "[statsOverflow](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)" page :)

The question above is a bit unclear to me, but in discrete cases you would calculate the variance with the following algorithm:

```
data_type getVariance(data_type[] array){
    data_type mean = getMean(array);
    data_type var = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++){
        var += getProbabilityOf(array[i])*(array[i]-mean)*(array[i]-mean);
    }
    return var;
}
data_type getMean(data_type[] array){
    data_type mean = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++){
        mean += getProbabilityOf(array[i], array)*array[i];
    }
    return mean;
}
double getProbabilityOf(data_type data, data_type[] array){
    return [number of appearances of data in array / size of array];
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. the thing which is confusing me that we will take all the frequecies in data variabe to get probabilities can you please explain a little. how to get probabilty

Comment: (edited the answer)
Example:
Suppose we have the following sequence of 13 numbers 
`1 2 3 9 8 7 1 1 1 2 3 4 2`
The probability of encountering the number `2` is `3/13` (number of appearances over the total number of integers)

Comment: thaks for replying but again its not clear to me as i have different attributes in this case how would i calculate the probabilities i would calculate all the occurace of an attribute value for a given class to calculate it.

Comment: Sorry, but I am no statistician, nor do I understand your problem exactly. I just tried to help by providing a simple example of how to calculate the variance of simple data. As mentioned before, you'd find better assistance at the [statistical analysis site on stackexchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)